# Tomcat 8.5.60 version in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, tomcat8

I need to ask if tomcat 8.5.60 available in Ubuntu 20.04 repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat has been upgraded from tomcat8 to tomcat9 in Ubuntu 20.04. The closest you can get to installing tomcat 8.5.60 in Ubuntu 20.04 is to manually download (with wget) and install tomcat 8.5.30 from Ubuntu 18.04 in Ubuntu 20.04 (with an apt command). It's the same package and it's almost the same version (8.5.30 instead of 8.5.60).

Open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
wget -c http://launchpadlibrarian.net/366407131/tomcat8_8.5.30-1ubuntu1_all.deb http://launchpadlibrarian.net/366407127/tomcat8-common_8.5.30-1ubuntu1_all.deb http://launchpadlibrarian.net/366407125/libtomcat8-java_8.5.30-1ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./libtomcat8-java_8.5.30-1ubuntu1_all.deb ./tomcat8_8.5.30-1ubuntu1_all.deb ./tomcat8-common_8.5.30-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

No, tomcat 8.5 is not available in the official repository for Ubuntu 20.04 - [tomcat8 packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=tomcat8&searchon=names)

Comment: Any idea when will be available ?

Comment: Probably not at all. If you need version 8.5, you will have to install it manually.